# python PriorityQueue fails to add objects when priority is the same

Tags: python-3.x, comparator, priority-queue

When using a PriorityQueue to add `(priority, object)` pairs, if the priority of a new object is equal to that of an existing one, the `put()` operation will fail with a `TypeError: '<' is not implemented for objects of type <objtype>`, ie, it is trying to sort objects of equal priority by the object itself, and failing when the comparator is not assigned. How can I avoid this issue, in the case where I don't actually care about order if `priority` is equal?

Comment: I think you need to add a code example that illustrates the error.

Comment: I deleted this because it ended up being a duplicate that I missed. The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028394/2521423

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using queue.PriorityQueue, not caring about comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027861/using-queue-priorityqueue-not-caring-about-comparisons)