# Python help. If statement not working?

Tags: python, if-statement, text-files

I am trying to store a high-score in a txt doc and then read it to show it on screen. But when the score that the player got is higherreturning, I would like to change the high-score in the txt file.
I know approximately how to do this but the If statement in my code has a little problem:
It keeps saying False...
Here is the code:

```
score = 10
highscoreFile = open('Highscore.txt', 'r+')
HS = highscoreFile.read() #the HS is, let's say, 3
highscoreFile.close()
print 'Your score is', score
print 'The High-Score is', HS
if score > HS:
    print 'newHS'
    newHS = True
    highscoreFile = open('Highscore.txt', 'w+')
    highscoreFile.write('%s' %(score))
    highscoreFile.close()
```

NOTE: if I put '<' instead for the If statement, it returns True... please explain.

Comment: You are comparing `int` and `string`.

Comment: Surprising that typos, FAQs deserve multiple answers.

Comment: How do I convert the srting into an integer? @devnull

Comment: @user3580258 you can convert `string` to `int` using `int(HS)`

Comment: The documentation has a purpose.  One of which is that users should read it.  http://docs.pythom.org

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is int(50)<str(5) in python 2.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266918/why-is-int50str5-in-python-2-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) reads the entire file, by default. And that will be treated as a string in Python. Quoting from the documentation,

> If the size argument is negative or omitted, **read all data until EOF is reached**. The bytes are **returned as a string object.**

So, you have to explicitly convert the string to a number, like this

```
HS = int(highscoreFile.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `int` with `string`.
The line

```
if score > HS:
```

should be ,

```
if score > int(HS):
```